# onBackgroundMessage open specified page

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, i'm trying to handle onBackgroundMessage. I already able to handle onMessage, onResume & onLaunch.

here my `myBackgroundMessageHandler` to handle `onBackgroundMessage`

```
static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(
      Map<String, dynamic> message) {}
```

i want to open specified page at my `myBackgroundMessageHandler`. On `onResume` i can do this

```
   Data data = Data(
          clickAction: message['data']['click_action'],
          sound: message['data']['sound'],
          status: message['data']['status'],
          screen: message['data']['screen'],
          extradata: message['data']['extradata'],
        );

        if (data.screen == "MAINTENANCE_DETAIL") {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => new MaintenanceDetail(
                RequestMaintenanceCode: data.extradata,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
```

But, when i copy it to my `myBackgroundMessageHandler`. I get this error

```
Error: Getter not found: 'context'.
```

I think the error is because `myBackgroundMessageHandler` is static method, so how can i open screen inside `myBackgroundMessageHandler` ?

Comment: The app is in the background at the point of that method being called, so it cannot navigate anywhere. Navigation is only possible while the app is in the foreground. What you should be able to do is persist the information (for example in Shared Preferences), and read that information when the app is resumed, and navigate based on that.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

`onBackgroundMessage` works in background, that so you cannot navigate to your routes. Best way is on your base class, check notifications on `initState()`. This helps to navigate route immediately. I mean, check the notification and navigate before the build method runs. There isn't another way to do.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.microtask(() {
      Provider.of<BaseViewBloc>(context).initFCM(); // This line check the notifications.
  });
```

---

These lines help to navigate:

```
  Future<void> onResume(Map<String, dynamic> message, context) async {
    print('onResume $message');
    var data = message["data"];
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, NotificationContentPage.routeName,
        arguments: int.parse(data["id"]));
  }

  Future<void> onLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> message, context) async {
    print('on launch $message');
    var data = message["data"];
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, NotificationContentPage.routeName,
        arguments: int.parse(data["id"]));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app main screen (view) use:

```
@override
  void initState() {    
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((fcmMessage) {
      print('Firebase-> onMessageOpenedApp: message clicked');
      displayMessage(fcmMessage);
    });

  }
```

Where (displayMessage) is a function to display your clicked message.
the key function here is (FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp)

Answer (score -2):

When a user will click your notification then app will open and below method will be called. So pass context in fcm init method and you can easily navigate to the applicable screen.

```
// onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    if (message['data']['notification_type'] == 'sell') {
      //Navigate now
    }
  },
```